# Triggered ANR, Root blocking Android Issue

Tags: java, android

I am facing an issue in my android app. The issue logged in the firebase crashlytics, Tagged under "Triggered ANR" and "Root Blocking". Unable to fix this issue. following crashlytics logs and code snippet.

**logs**

> main (runnable): tid=1 systid=32748
> #00 pc 0x47a6ec libart.so
> #01 pc 0x57f510 libart.so
> #02 pc 0x59c35c libart.so
> #03 pc 0x5801ec libart.so
> #04 pc 0x61f318 libart.so
> at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newUnpaddedArray(VMRuntime.java)
> at com.android.internal.util.ArrayUtils.newUnpaddedIntArray(ArrayUtils.java:61)
> at android.text.AutoGrowArray$IntArray.ensureCapacity(AutoGrowArray.java:210)
> at android.text.AutoGrowArray$IntArray.append(AutoGrowArray.java:199)
> at android.text.MeasuredParagraph.applyMetricsAffectingSpan(MeasuredParagraph.java:612)
> at android.text.MeasuredParagraph.buildForStaticLayout(MeasuredParagraph.java:427)
> at android.text.PrecomputedText.createMeasuredParagraphs(PrecomputedText.java:436)
> at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:683)
> at android.text.StaticLayout.(StaticLayout.java:591)
> at android.text.StaticLayout.(StaticLayout.java:49)
> at android.text.StaticLayout$Builder.build(StaticLayout.java:416)
> at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:9311)
> at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:9130)
> at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:9817)
> at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6403)
> at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6218)
> at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6170)
> at com.gobillion.android.commerce.firebase.FirebaseRealtimeDBSetup$1$1$1.run(FirebaseRealtimeDBSetup.java)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8183)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1015)

**code**

```
 try {  
Handler handler = new Handler();
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot1.hasChildren()) {
                                        Data data = dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserMessageData.class);
                                        dataList.add(data);
                                    }
                                }
                                final Spannable messageString = convertIntoSpannable(context, dataList);
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (ObjectUtil.isNotNull(messageString) && messageString.length() > 0) {
                                            parent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            tickertextView.setText(messageString);
                                        } else {
                                            parent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }).start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        parent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

**method1**

        public static SpannableStringBuilder convertIntoSpannable(Context context, List<Data> dataList){
            SpannableStringBuilder messageSpannable = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            if(!dataList.isEmpty()) {
                        for(Data data: dataList){
                            if(ObjectUtil.isNotNullOrNotEmpty(data.message))
                                messageSpannable.append(TextViewUtils.setBulletString(data.message,context)) ;
                        }
                    }
            return messageSpannable;
        }
```

**method2**

```
 public static  Spanned setBulletString(String message, Context context) {
        return Html.fromHtml(String.format(
                context.getString(R.string.dot_data) + message + "\t\t"), new Html.ImageGetter() {
            @Override
            public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                Drawable d = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.green_dot, null);
                d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                return d;
            }
        }, null);
    }
```